# How to fix save button

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbcommand

I wrote a code for my pleasure.
i have access data file "mdb" and i show him on gridview from gridview i select row and shown on text box.
i edit the textbox and try to press on Save button and show me error msg.
what i do wrong? 
save button didnt save and show me error msg.

add pictures and my code:

[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAsV5.png)

[gridview+textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8A1d.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Center image description hereDHW
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:\Users\RBA\Desktop\123\users1.mdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.Show();

        }


        private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "insert into GRL1 (NoBoard,Site,Group,Kind,Unit) values ('" + txt_noboard.Text + "','" + txt_site.Text + "','" + txt_group.Text + "','" + txt_kind.Text + "','" + txt_unit.Text + "',)";

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error  " + ex);
            }
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'users1DataSet.GRL1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.gRL1TableAdapter.Fill(this.users1DataSet.GRL1);

        }

        private void btn_loadGR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string query = "select * from GRL1";
                command.CommandText = query;

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error  " + ex);
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string query = "select * from GRS1";
                command.CommandText = query;

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error  " + ex);
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

                txt_noboard.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                txt_site.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                txt_group.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                txt_kind.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                txt_unit.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                txt_com.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: there is a comma before the close brace in the insert statement. But fixing this simple typo will not save your code from serious problems like Sql Injection and troubles with parsing values. NEVER concatenate strings to build sql commands. Use parameters

Comment: i removed the comma and still same msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your sql text. There is a comma before the close brace. But there is also an error caused by the usage of a reserved keyword in MS-Access (Group). You need to put square brackets around that name.

Finally, do not use string concatenation to build sql commands but always use parameters.
This avoid sql injection hacks and remove problem with parsing your inputs (for example if there is a single quote in your input text the whole query will fail again with a syntax error)

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(....con string...))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            // Notice how Group field is between square brackets.
            // If you can I suggest to change the name of this field
            string cmdText = @"insert into GRL1 (NoBoard,Site,[Group],Kind,Unit) 
                          values (@nob, @sit, @grp, @knd, @uni)";
            command.CommandText = cmdText;
            // Is NoBoard an integer? If yes you should pass an integer not a string
            command.Parameters.Add("@nob", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_noboard.Text);
            command.Parameters.Add("@sit", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_site.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@grp", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_group.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@knd", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_kind.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@uni", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txt_unit.Text;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error  " + ex);
    }
}
```

The parameters collection is filled with the values required by your query text. Notice that I don't know exactly the datatype of your columns in the database. The parameter OleDbType should exactly match the types expected to avoid Type Mismatch exceptions

Last tip. Connections should be created, opened and closed when needed. Do not keep a global connection object. You don't get much gain in performance because ADO.NET employs a technique called Connection Pooling

Comment: Sorry, I have made some confusion with VB.NET. Of course the  _...con string..._  is just a placeholder where you should put your real connectionstring value.

Comment: can u write me please the code of  the save button?

Comment: I don't understand. This is the code for the save button.